# How to prevent a HttpClientFactory to log using NLOG.Web

Tags: nlog

I have started using the Asp.Net Core 2.1 HttpClientFactory

```
  services.AddHttpClient();
```

Now I get these huge logs from the HttpClient, every request logs Info and Trace level logs.

```
2018-11-08 14:34:59.6753|::1||INFO |8.11.7.0|12 |Dto|Log.RequestPipelineStart|Start processing HTTP request GET ...
```

I have been trying to throw them in a black hole:

```
 <logger name="System.Net.Http.HttpClient*" minlevel ="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
```

But that does not help. Any suggestions?

Full Nlog:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       internalLogToConsoleError="true"
       internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="logs\internal-nlog.txt"
      throwExceptions="true"
      autoReload="true">

  <!-- Load the ASP.NET Core plugin -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>

  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets async="true">
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="logs\${machinename}-all.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${aspnet-Request-Method}|${message}|${exception}"
            maxArchiveFiles="7"
            archiveFileName="logs\archive\${machinename}-all.{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            enableArchiveFileCompression ="true"
    />
    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-trace" fileName="logs\${machinename}-trace.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=-3:${threadid}}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}|${message}|${exception}"
            maxArchiveFiles="14"
            archiveFileName="logs\archive\${machinename}-trace.{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveEvery="Saturday"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            enableArchiveFileCompression ="true"
            />
    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-error" fileName="logs\${machinename}-error.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}||${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=-3:${threadid}}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
            maxArchiveFiles="100"
            archiveFileName="logs\archive\${machinename}-error.{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            enableArchiveFileCompression ="true"
    />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-info" fileName="logs\${machinename}-info.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}|${message}|${exception}"
            maxArchiveFiles="36"
            archiveFileName="logs\archive\${machinename}-info.{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveEvery="Month"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
            enableArchiveFileCompression ="true"
    />
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
            name="ColoredConsole"
            layout="${aspnet-User-Identity}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception}"
            header="${longdate}"
            footer="${longdate}"
            useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="True"

            detectConsoleAvailable="True">
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="LimitingWrapper"
           name="MailTarget"
           messageLimit="1"
           interval="00:15">
      <target xsi:type="Mail"
              layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}||${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=-3:${threadid}}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
              subject ="Error in Testmij"
              to="info@datec.nl"
              from="testmijonline@testmij.nl"
              body="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}||${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=-3:${threadid}}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
              smtpUserName ="mail@smtp.datec.nl"
              enableSsl ="false"
              smtpPassword ="7dnV&amp;q#D3s"
              smtpAuthentication ="Basic"
              smtpServer ="smtp.datec.nl "
              smtpPort ="25"
      />
    </target>
    <!-- write to the void aka just remove -->
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile"/>

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="DTOWEB.Models.HttpClientExtensions" writeTo="blackhole"  final="true" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="System.Net.Http.HttpClient*" minlevel ="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ownFile-error"  />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-trace"  />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="ownFile-info" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ColoredConsole" />
    <logger name ="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo ="MailTarget"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Could you show the entire NLog.config? Have you checked that your NLog.config is deployed properly? Btw. if you remove `writeTo="blackhole"` then it will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks, when deploying in to test or production the nlog gets deployed automatically, but when I do a debug run on my PC, it does not.
I now removed the writeTo="blackhole", thanks for the tip. The writeTo="blackhole" is described in the tutorial

Comment: Could you give a link to that tutorial? Maybe it can be fixed for future readers.

Comment: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Null-target

Answer (score 2):

Answered, see comment of Rolf Kristensen

When you run a debug session in localhost, Visual Studio does not deploy all files to the bin directory. So the changed Nlog.config was not deployed.

Comment: Please describe the answer here, so it's a real answer